# Publisher 2007 files created on Vista 32 bit won't open on Vista 64 bit

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

I created several documents in MS Office Publisher 2007 when I was using Windows Vista 32 bit version. I've recently upgraded to the 64 bit version of Vista and am now having trouble opening the files created on the previous Windows setup.

When I try to open my documents, I get this warning:

> Publisher can not open the document.

How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: Can you confirm you are able to open Publisher files created with this new installation on Windows 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaprograms/thread/2d222ce3-c6d9-4be7-8e2f-4bfe3ea03971) site :

> On the same screen as the Recommended Programs suggested for the program to open the file, you will probably have to click the "Browse" button and locate the Publisher file through there.
>   It may be located in this folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office".
>
> You can check by Click on the Windows Orb and typing "publisher" in the search field.
>   Right click on the entry that appears, click on "Properties", then click on the "General" tab.
>   You will find the address to the program next to the "Location" entry.